# Handling Soft Keyboard Navigation Arrows

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-keypad

Here i am using ViewPager for Fragments, i used custom view pager for controlling navigation.
here is the class,

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setMyScroller();
}

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setMyScroller();
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

//down one is added for smooth scrolling

private void setMyScroller() {
    try {
        Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
        Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        scroller.setAccessible(true);
        scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
    public MyScroller(Context context) {
        super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
    }
}
```

}

There no Swipe and Click Events working. but what is my problem is

[image] when i select **FIRST NAME** and click on the arrow button on my tablet (Samsung) it navigates to **MIDDLE NAME** then to **LAST NAME**, after **LAST NAME** it **NAVIGATES TO  THE NEXT FRAGMENT** ie; INTRODUCTION tab on my view pager.
this is my problem, how to prevent this?

what i tried is, i set EditText property `nextFocusForward`, and tried

```
 v.setFocusableInTouchMode(true); 
 v.requestFocus(); 
 v.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() { 
    @Override 
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_NAVIGATE_NEXT) {
            return false; 
          } 
      } 
      return false; 
    } 
});
```

but no good!
how to hide that soft key ? or how to control the action?
the problem is only with this keyboard,(on Samsung Tab) on my phone there is no keys like this.
how to get rid of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late but may it help someone.

Try to use dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) in your Project

```
@Override public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

     Log.i("key pressed", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
     if(event.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.KEY_A/*select required keycode*/){

        //perform required  task

     }
     return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event); 
}
```

it is returning you a keyCode check the keycode for navigation_next button.

Hope this will help you.