# Handle keyboard navigation arrows

Tags: android, android-viewpager

On a Samsung Tablet, we have the following keyboard:
[image]

When a clic occurred on the right bottom arrows, in the view pager, fragment is changed. I want to intercept this event or remove the arrows from the keyboard. Is it possible ?

I tried to intercept keyevent with onKeyUp and onKeyDown methods, but it's not working:

```
if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT || event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT) {
  return true;
}
```

My problem is the same as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43556148/handling-soft-keyboard-navigation-arrows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)`:

```
 @Override 
 public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {

     Log.i("key pressed ", String.valueOf(event.getKeyCode()));
     if(event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEY_A /*select required keycode*/ ){
        // perform task
     }
     return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event); 
}
```

Comment: it is returning you a keyCode check the keycode for navigation_next button.

Comment: After 1 day with this problem you saved my day! Thank you a lot!